# Anglesharp converts single quotes into double quotes?

Tags: anglesharp

It appears that AngleSharp converts single quotes into double quotes.  Is this true?  If so, it affects me being able to get JSON data from a request.  I'm calling a controller that returns html wrapped in a json object.  Part of the html has attributes using single quotes. After calling the OpenAsync method, the resulting document converts them into double quotes.  So when I then use Newtonsoft.Json, it tries to deserialize based on those.  Is there a way to keep that from happening through a configuration settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong. AngleSharp follows the HTML spec. and outputs all HTML with a default serializer, which uses double quotes for, e.g., attributes. For your JSON data you don't have to worry.

It sounds to me that you download something that was never supposed to be deserialized and serialized again. If you present a little bit more details what you actually try to do (present a MWE please) I can go into details what should be changed / could be done to achieve what you try to do.

Comment: I've figured out another way to do this by just using WebClient.  Thank you for your time however.